# Can you help me with -3 weeks ago / 3 weeks before now

Tags: prepositions, conjunctions

I know that later can be replaced by after s + v like the following.

> 1. I wake up at 10 but I get up ***about an hour after I wake up.***
> 2. I wake up at 10 but I get up ***about an hour later.***

Then, how about this?

> 3. Since 3 weeks **ago**, I have been dating her.
> 4. Since 3 weeks **before now**, I have been dating her.

I just want to know more expression that is the same meaning as ***"ago"***, so that I can use more sentences.

Or better,

> 5. I met a girl 3 weeks ago.
> 6. I met a girl 3 weeks before now.

Are these possible?

Comment: They're all possible, but #1, #3 and #5 are more colloquial. #2,  #4 and #6 just use too many words. In #2, it's already established _when_ he woke up, so saying "after I wake up" is redundant.  For # 4 and #6; we almost always say it the shorter way, with "ago" (#3 and #5).

Comment: Actually, #2 is more colloquial (I think @BrianHitchcock meant to say 2 instead of 1 in his comment). It's shorter, so English speakers will tend to say that more than the lengthier sentence.

Answer (score 1):

> 3. Since 3 weeks ago, I have been dating her.
> 4. Since 3 weeks before now, I have been dating her.

For a time period, it is better to use *for*

> I have been dating her for 3 weeks.

*Since* is usually used when you refer to a date

> I have been dating her since May

For your other sentences, number (2) and (5) are preferred as they use *later* and *ago*. When you can say something using a short adverb, it's redundant to repeat your words (*after I wake up* is redundant)

For (5) you may also say:

> It's 3 weeks from when I first met her.
>
> It's 3 weeks since I first met her.